# Godaddy не отправляет письмо

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

Добрый день, godaddy не отправляет письма, пробовал на другом хостинге все путем, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема? Код отправки привожу ниже.

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net');    

$file = "./tmp/file.pdf"; // файл
$mailTo = $email; // кому
$from = '****@*****.com'; // от кого
$subject = "Test file"; // тема письма
$message = "Тестовое письмо с вложением"; // текст письма

$separator = "---"; // разделитель в письме
// Заголовки для письма
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n"; // задаем от кого письмо
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$separator\""; // в заголовке указываем разделитель
// если письмо с вложением
if($file){
    $bodyMail = "--$separator\n"; // начало тела письма, выводим разделитель
    $bodyMail .= "Content-type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n"; // кодировка письма
    $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable"; // задаем конвертацию письма
    $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n"; // задаем название файла
    $bodyMail .= $message."\n"; // добавляем текст письма
    $bodyMail .= "--$separator\n";
    $fileRead = fopen($file, 'r');
    $contentFile = fread($fileRead, filesize($file)); // считываем его до конца
    fclose($fileRead); // закрываем файл
    $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n";
    $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; // кодировка файла
    $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n";
    $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile))."\n"; // кодируем и прикрепляем файл
    $bodyMail .= "--".$separator ."--\n";
// письмо без вложения
}
$result = mail($mailTo, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers);
```

Comment: а что выдает telnet? проходит по 25 порту? некоторые провайдеры (особенно западные) по умолчанию его блокируют, чтобы не рассылали спам (открывают доступ после проверки личности администратора). попробуйте команду `telnet smtp.mail.ru 25`

Comment: да, 25 порт стоит

Comment: нет, а что именно выдает telnet? проходит соединение? попробуйте отправить письмо из командной строки `mail -s "Test" your@mail.com`

Comment: Локально работает? На хостинге только не работает? Если да, то на какую почту отсылаете? Пробовали других